# Grouping a table issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by

I have the table with four fields: `ID`, `DateBeg`, `DateEnd`, and `RankID`. `RankID` value is rank of the `ID` field over `DateBeg` asc. here's sample data:

```
ID |RankID |  DateBeg    |  DateEnd  |
---|-------|--------------------------
1  | 1     |01-01-2016   |04-01-2016 |
1  | 2     |05-01-2016   |11-02-2016 |
1  | 3     |12-02-2016   |15-02-2016 |
1  | 4     |16-02-2016   |19-02-2016 |
1  | 5     |23-02-2016   |25-02-2016 |
4  | 2     |05-01-2016   |07-01-2016 |
4  | 3     |08-01-2016   |12-01-2016 |
5  | 1     |04-01-2016   |06-01-2016 |
```

Now, I want to group the ID records, which have `DateBeg` value 1 day after the previous rank records `DateEnd` value(if it is null, it must be included too).
the desired result of this example table will be:

```
ID | Min(DateBeg)|Max(DateEnd)|
---|-------------|----------------
1  |01-01-2016   |19-02-2016  |
1  |23-02-2016   |25-02-2016  |
4  |05-01-2016   |12-01-2016  |
5  |04-01-2016   |06-01-2016  |
```

Hope You can help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: What is the RankID for? This looks redundant, as the order is the same as the dates. Or does RankID have another special meaning? If it doesn't, I would remove it from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the algorithm:

1. Detect the gaps. Give each record that doesn't follow the previous records immediately a gap #1. So each record starting a new group is flagged then with a #1.
2. Build a running total of the gap numbers. Thus all records of a group get the same number.
3. Group by the groups found and show minimum start date and maximum end date per group.

The SQL Server query:

```
select id, min(datebeg), max(dateend)
from
(
  select
    id,
    datebeg,
    dateend,
    sum(gap) over (partition by id order by datebeg) as grp
  from
  (
    select 
      id,
      datebeg,
      dateend,
      case when datebeg <> 
                dateadd(day, 1, lag(dateend) over (partition by id order by datebeg)) 
           then 1 else 0 end as gap
    from mytable
  ) with_gap_flags
) with_group_numbers
group by id, grp
order by id, grp;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f473ae/1

Comment: I'm moving my accept to this answer, as this is much complete one.

Answer (score 3):

Try Like below. I assume your `datebeg` and `Dateend` are uin date data type format. Otherwise you need to convert into date data type for comparision.

```
SELECT ID,MIN(DATEBEG),MAX(DateEnd) FROM
    (
    SELECT ID,(DATEBEG),ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) RNO,

    (DateEND),CASE WHEN DATEBEG=LAG( DATEADD(DAY,1,[DateEnd])) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)THEN  1 END  NO
    FROM #TABLE1
    )A
    GROUP BY ID,ISNULL(NO,RNO)
    ORDER BY ID
```

**Update**: -
Try below. It will work for all scenarios if you have unique ud and rank id combinations in your data set otherwise use row_number and generate unique numbers.

```
SELECT ID,MIN(DATEBEG),MAX(DATEEND) FROM 
(
SELECT ID,
       RANKID,
       datebeg, 
      DateEnd,
       CASE
         WHEN Dateadd(DAY, -1,  datebeg) = Lag( DateEnd) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)                                                        
       OR   Dateadd(DAY, 1, dateEND) = LEAD( DateBeg) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)                                                       
      THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END NO
FROM   #Table1 
)A
GROUP BY ID,CASE WHEN NO=0 AND ID<>RANKID THEN RANKID ELSE NO END
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f473ae/3

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, You're right, after we will have the gaps, this query will return false results.

Comment: @TedoG. Even above answer also gives false results. I am going to update my post soon.

Comment: @Buddi, I did not find any case when the above query is false, can you give an example?

Comment: @TedoG.Couldn't able to recollect it that scenario. When i was testing above solution it fails. i am not sure what scenario it is.